# Return dynamic array from a function, and assign to a suitable variable

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I have the following function.

```
char* readFile(const char *fileName){
   std::ifstream file(fileName);
   char *str[50];
   int count=0;
   if(file){
      str[0] = new char[50];
      while(file.getline(str[count], 50)){
         count++;
         str[count] = new char[50];
      }
   }
   return str;
}
```

**The behavior of the previous function is:**

- Read the content of text file line by line.
- Save each line in item of the 2D array.
- Then return dynamic 2D array.

Now, I want to assign the 2D array that returned from function to a suitable variable, or I want to return reference to that dynamic 2D array ?

Comment: Unless this is an exercise in masochism, consider something on the general order of: `std::vector<std::string> lines; while (std::getline(file, line) lines.push_back(line);`.

Answer (score 1):

DON'T DO THAT!!!

You cannot allocate an array ... or an array of arrays ... inside of a subroutine, and then return it to the caller like that.

SUGGESTIONS:

1) declare "char *str[50]" in the CALLER (not inside the subroutine) and pass it in

... or ...

2) "new" inside the caller.  "new" allocates from heap; omitting it allocates from the stack.

3) use std::vector<> instead of a simple array

IMHO...

Comment: You certainly *can* allocate an array and return it to the caller. I agree that you usually *shouldn't*, since it makes memory management error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the suggestions/warnings that people have already made to you, your function header should be `char **readFile(const char *fileName)`.

And to avoid heap memory corrupting, you should declare that array of pointers as follows:

```
char **str;
str = new char*[50];
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do like This**

```
int** createMatrix(int row , int column)
{
    int **tem = new int*[row];
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        tem[i] = new int [column];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
        {
            tem[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    return tem;
}

int main()
{
    int row=5;int column=1;
   int **arr=createMatrix(row,column);

   for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<column;j++){
    cout<<arr[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
   }
}
```